# Restful jboss Deserialize

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest, jboss

I am building a restful webservice in JBoss AS 7.1.1 Final. It works great, until I need a custom deserializer. Code:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "tipo")
@Table(name = "debitavel", schema = "despesas_db")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@JsonDeserialize(using = DebitavelDeserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = DebitavelSerializer.class)
public abstract class Debitavel {

}
```

This class have 2 subclass:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "conta", schema = "despesas_db")
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "CONTA")
public class Conta extends Debitavel {
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "CONTA")
@Table(name = "cartao", schema = "despesas_db")
public class CartaoCredito extends Debitavel {
}
```

And I have this class uses a Debitavel:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "despesa", schema = "despesas_db")
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "D")
public class Despesa {

    @Column
    private String descricao;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "debitavel_id")
    protected Debitavel debitavel;

}
```

So in the page I send a json like that

```
{
    "descricao": "TESTE",
    "debitavel": {
         "id": 101,
         "descricao": "Conta1",
         "cor": "#ff0000",
         "tipo": "CONTA"
    }
}
```

So, I wanna a class that create a instance of CartaoCredito or Conta, based in the atributte tipo, so I build a deserializer:

```
public class DebitavelDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Debitavel> {

      @Override
      public Debitavel deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)     throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
              //staff to create Conta or CartaoCredito
      }
```

}

And my pom.xml:

```
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.12</version>
        </dependency>
```

However, when I tried deploy the app, jboss says that Debitavel is a abstract class and it can not build a instance. I looked for the solution and I tried a several solutions:

- Create a jboss-deployment-structure.xml with the modules from jboss and change the pom.xml to provided;
- Change the intire resteasy module;
- Change to new jackson 2.x;

It seens that the jboss simplely ignore those annotations.

tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved... but to be honest I don't understand why, so lets see:

I changed the pom.xml to

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

And all works just fine. Someone could explain why this works?

Comment: Adding dependency from resteasy-jackson-provider help me too.